# Problems with Tumblr and custom domain (getting both www. and without www. to work)

Tags: dns, tumblr

I'm trying to connect my Tumblr with my custom domain - currently I have no A records, just two CNAME records:

> *.mydomain.com -- domains.tumblr.com
>   www.mydomain.com -- domains.tumblr.com

My Tumblr is set up to connect to www.mydomain.com and currently it works correctly when I access it via www.mydomain.com; however, I need to make the http://mydomain.com address also work. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

the official tumblr document as of writing says do an A record for the mydomain.com to the Tumblr IP,  OR use a CNAME if it is www.mydomain.com you want to use to domains.tumblr.com. http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains

I think you can do both also but not tried this yet. (Seen referenced in other posts on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Add a CNAME record for the second-level domain as well:

```
mydomain.com -- domains.tumblr.com
```

The version `*.mydomain.com` would affect only domains like `foo.mydomain.com` and `bar.mydomain.com`, not the second-level domain itself.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. Unfortunately the issue is that Network Solutions' backend form for CNAME records doesn't easily allow the Alias for http://foryouthetraveller.com to be noted. They must have a notation for it that I can't figure out

Comment: Seem like they forbid it for suspicious reasons http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-manage-advanced-dns-records/

Comment: ok i somehow made it work for future people: so i only had those two cname records, no a records. i added an record for @ (none) (meaning http://mydomain.com) to Tumblr's IP address 66.6. 44.4

Comment: I gather that CNAME on root is not best practice http://joshstrange.com/why-its-a-bad-idea-to-put-a-cname-record-on-your-root-domain/ I'm going to try an A record on root and www as a CNAME like the above poster.